# Login Page - AD - Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, database, active-directory

I need to create a login page which should authenticate with our Active directory details.

I created a login page in Php. Usually, I used to store the id and password in Xampp, but for this scenario, I don't have any specific idea how to authenticate to the Active directory.

I am new to this. I have the script. but it is not authenticating AD.

Do I need to know what is the credentials I need if I want to connect with AD?
Can I simplify this below program?
What I need to write exactly in the place of mydomain in program?
I am using Xampp now. Do I need to download any other application?

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$adServer = "ldap://hostname.com";

$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$ldaprdn = 'mydomain' . "\\" . $username;

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);


if ($bind) {
    $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=COM",$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
    {
        if($info['count'] > 1)
            break;
        echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($info);
        echo '</pre>';
        $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
    }
    @ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
    $msg = "Invalid email address / password";
    echo $msg;
   }

  }

   else{
 ?>
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
    <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php in particular http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php I'm still going to vote to close this question as "too broad" for stackoverflow.

Comment: you can use this library -> [jasny](https://github.com/jasny/auth)

Answer (score 0):

To get that script working, you'll need to edit a few things:

`$adServer = "ldap://fullfqdn.ofyour.server";`

or (ip is an example only)

`$adServer = "ldap://192.168.1.1";`

then you have to enter your domain name. If your domain is example.com, just put example.

`$ldaprdn = 'example' . "\\" . $username;`

Then you'll need to know the base context of the AD. That it just your domain name. If it's example.com then it becomes dc=example,dc=com

`$result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=example,dc=com",$filter);ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");`

If it doesn't return anything, change the "sn" to "cn" in your search, as your "sn" field might not be populated.

`$result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=example,dc=com",$filter);ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"cn");`